# Airbnb/react-dates with a redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-dates

I can fire the calendar of AirBnb react-dates within the render function of React,but if I try out in a function referenced within  of redux-form, there is no error and it display the initial dates correctly but when clicking don't fire the calendar

```
BELOW WORKS
class Landing extends React.Component {
    state
    ....
     render(){
         return (<form>
                  <DateRangePicker (+props) />
                </form>)
      }
}

BELOW DISPLAY THE INITIAL FIELDS WITH THE DATES AND THERE ARE NO 
ERRORS, BUT WHEN CLICKING DON'T FIRE THE CALENDAR
 Class Landing extends React.Component {
    state
    ....
     renderCalendar=()=>{
          return (<DateRangePicker (+props)/>)
       }
     render(){
         return (
           <form>
             <Field component={this.renderCalendar}/>// Field from 
                                                        react-redux
           </form>
          )
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this instead? `<Field component={DateRangePicker} />`

Comment: It is no working, because we miss the props.                                                                                                                            <DateRangePicker
                        startDate={this.state.startDate}
                        startDateId="start"
                        endDate={this.state.endDate}
                        endDateId="end"
                        onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
                        focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput}
                        onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
                    />

Comment: Are you trying to use this inside a dialog (e.g. with Material UI)?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted taking away all the code of react-dates to another component. So, I have two components: In one component is the code of redux-form and where importing the custom component DatePicker. In the component DatePicker is where I placed all regarding react-dates with its component                           The trick worked.